# Bucket sort or merge sort?

Tags: c++, sorting, mergesort, bucket-sort

I am doing an c++ assignment where I have to sort data (n=400) which is student scores from 0-100. I am confused on using bucket sort, which sorts algorithm into buckets or merge sort, which divides and conquers. Which one should I use and why?

Comment: Use std::sort (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort). Why? : The best code you can use has already been tested (and in this case already optimized).

Comment: @PepijnKramer if he turns in an assignment which is just a call to `std::sort()`, and the assignment is to implement a sorting algorithm, I don't think he'll get a very good grade :)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I know ;) But the question only stated he had to sort data. And then reuse is the better option and his time is better spent on other parts of the assignment.

Comment: Assuming the distribution is guassian, bucket sort is probably best. Adopt your bucket sizes with this knowledge e.g. larger bucket ranges of low and high scores and smaller buckets for average scores.

Comment: Are the scores integers or float?

Answer (score 2):

## Update

Read Thomas Mailund's answer first. He provided more relevant answer to this specific question. Since the scores are likely to be in integers, histogram sort (variant of bucket sort) should be faster than merge sort!

---

Bucket sort performs poorly when the data set is not distributed well since most of the items will fall into a few popular buckets. In your case, It's reasonable to assume that the most of the student scores will more or less be around the median score and only have few outliers. Therefore I would argue that the merge sort performs better in this context since it is not affected by the distribution of the data set.

### Additional Consideration

There could be an argument that bucket sort is better if we can adjust the bucket ranges according to the expected distribution of the data set. Sure, if we hit the jackpot and predicted the distribution really well, it can significantly speed up the sorting process. However, the downside of this is that the sorting performance can plummet when our prediction goes wrong i.e. getting unexpected data set. For example, the test being too easy/difficult might lead to this "unexpected data set" in the context of this question. In other words, bucket sort has better best-case time complexity, where as merge sort has better worst-case time complexity. Which metric to use for comparing algorithms depends on the needs of each application. In practice, the worst-case time complexity is usually found to be more useful and I think the same could be said for this specific question. It's also a plus that we don't suffer the additional cost of calculating/adjusting the bucket ranges if we go for merge sort.

Comment: Why would bucket sort depend on the distribution of the keys? It should be agnostic to that, unless there are caching reasons, but then I would expect it to do well with clustered data

Comment: @ThomasMailund Bucket sort is a distribution sort. It's computational complexity depends on the algorithm used to sort each bucket, the number of buckets to use, and whether the input is uniformly distributed. It can NOT be agnostic to the distribution of the data :)

Comment: My implementation in the answer below is, though. It does two scans through the input regardless of how the keys are distributed. Are we talking about different bucket sorts?

Comment: Ah, I guess what I’m thinking of is histogram sort. A variant of bucket sort. It is applicable here, though, if the scores are integers from zero to 100

Comment: @ThomasMailund You're right. In the context of this question, the OP should go for histogram sort and that'll be faster than merge sort! I suppose that's why there is a comment about whether the scores are integer or float.

Comment: They would have to be integers for histogram sort to work, yes.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on your data. However, merge sort will run in O(n log n) while bucket sort will run in O(n + b) where b is the number of buckets you have. If scores are from zero to (and including) 100, then b is 101. So the question is of O(n log n) runs faster than O(n + 101) which is an easy question to answer theoretically, since O(n + 101) = O(n) and clearly O(n) is faster than O(n log n). Even if we did the (admittedly silly) exercise of substituting n for 400 we would get 501 for bucket sort and with log2(400) = 9 (rounded up) 3600 for merge sort. But that is silly, because big-O notation doesn't work that way. Theoretically, we would just conclude that O(n) is better than O(n log n).

But that is the theoretical answer. In practise, the overhead hidden behind the big-O counts, and then it might not be as simple.

That being said, the overhead in bucket sort is usually smaller than for merge sort. You need to allocate an array for some counts and an array to put the output in, and after that you need to run through the input twice, first for counting and then for sorting. A simple bucket sort could look like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// Some fake data
struct student
{
    int score;
    std::string name;
};
struct student scores[] = {
    {45, "jack"},
    {12, "jill"},
    {99, "john"},
    {89, "james"}};

void bucket_sort(int n, struct student in[n], struct student out[n])
{
    int buckets[101]; // range 0-100 with 100 included
    for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++)
    {
        buckets[i] = 0;
    }

    // get offsets for each bucket
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        buckets[in[i].score]++;
    }
    int acc = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++)
    {
        int b = buckets[i];
        buckets[i] = acc;
        acc += b;
    }

    // Bucket the scores
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        out[buckets[in[i].score]++] = in[i];
    }
}

void print_students(int n, struct student students[n])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        std::cout << students[i].score << ' ' << students[i].name << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main(void)
{

    int no_students = sizeof scores / sizeof scores[0];
    print_students(no_students, scores);

    struct student sorted[no_students];
    bucket_sort(no_students, scores, sorted);
    print_students(no_students, sorted);

    return 0;
}
```

(excuse my C++, it's been more than 10 years since I used the language, so the code might look a bit more C like than it should).

The best way to work out what is faster in practise is, of course, to measure it. Compare `std::sort` with something like the above, and you should get your answer.

If it wasn't for an assignment, though, I wouldn't recommend you to experiment. The built-in `std::sort` can easily handle 400 elements faster than you need, and there is no need to implement new sorting algorithms for something like that. For an exercise, though, it could be fun to do some measuring and experiments.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not precise enough: *I have to sort data (n=400) which is student scores from 0-100*.

If the grades are integers, [bucket sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort) with 1 bucket per grade, also called histogram sort or [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) will do the job in linear time as illustrated in *Thomas Mailund*'s answer.

If the grades are decimal, bucket sort will just add complexity and given the sample size, mergesort will do just fine in **O(n.log(n))** time with a classic implementation.

If the goal of the question is for you to implement a sorting algorithm, the above applies, otherwise you should just use `std::sort` in C++ or `qsort` in C with an appropriate comparison function.